# Symfony2: Right usage of controller

Tags: php, symfony, controller

I'm building few pages application. And wanted to ask what's the right way to use the controller?

Each page having a controller? Or putting pages as methods in same controller? In my case I'm using database and I really can't keep everything in one method. In this case I created Helper class helping me to keep and produce some of the code there.

Controller:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    //main method that performs as page
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $helper = new IgnasHelper();
    $profile = $this->profileQuery($helper);

    return $this->render(
        'IgnasIgnasBundle:Default:index.html.twig',
        array('profile' => $profile)
        );
    }

    //method that returns database's data back to main index method
    public function profileQuery(IgnasHelper $helper)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $selectAll = array('p.id', 'p.first', 'p.last', 'p.birth', 'p.country', 'p.city', 'p.email');
        $profile = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select($selectAll)
            ->from('IgnasIgnasBundle:Profilis', 'p')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

        return $helper->profileArray($profile);
    }
}
```

And now Helper class:

```
public function profileArray(array $profile)
{
    $id = $profile[0]['id'];
    $first = $profile[0]['first'];
    $last = $profile[0]['last'];
    $birth = $profile[0]['birth'];
    $country = $profile[0]['country'];
    $city = $profile[0]['city'];
    $email = $profile[0]['email'];

    return array(
        'id' => $id,
        'first' => $first,
        'last' => $last,
        'birth' => $birth,
        'country' => $country,
        'city' => $city,
        'email' => $email,
    );
}
```

So for other page I was thinking of making another controller to perform it. Am I using controllers properly?

Comment: for your profileArray function , you can only do return $profile[0]; and nothing else

Comment: Yes you're right I will do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use [Symfony Doctrine Repositories](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes)

Controllers are made for specfific actions: for example in a blog you can have an ArticleController, a CategoryController, etc...

You can have many methods in one controller, but it is better if methods have the same subject.

```
<?php
class CategoryController extends Controller
{

    function indexAction() { }
    function listArticleAction($catID) { }
    function createAction($catID) { }
    function renameAction($catID) { }
    [...]
}
```

When you want to make custom queries like in your profileQuery function, you should (must ?) use doctrine repositories.
After you can make something like

```
<?php
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$repo = $em->getRepository("YourBundle:YourEntity");
$list = $repo->whateverYouWantToDo();
```

Using that way has two main benefits :
- The first is that you don't overload the controller by using custom queries in wrong place.
- The second is you can use the repository methods wherever in your application (in another Bundle for example)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I was kinda asking about right usage of controllers, not databases :). I see the point here about repositories, but I can't find answer if I should keep 1 page = 1 method in same controller, or 1 page = 1 controller.

Comment: Edited post, tell me ;)*

Comment: So practically I can create a separate controller for each page right? :)

Comment: yes, it will york fine, but you will have a lot of Controllers then